# Как использоваться Pjax на сайте?

Tags: pjax, php

Как использоваться Pjax на сайте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите [Тут](http://freehabr.ru/blog/73.html)

Если с английским дружите, то [здесь лучше написано](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/README.md)!

Если коротко, то эта технология позволяет подгружать контент с другой страницы, меняя при этом URL страницы и, что самое интересное, не перегружаясь. 
Вот пример из второй ссылки:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- styles, scripts, etc -->
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
    Загрузить контент из <a href="/page/2">другой страницы</a>?.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Добавляем обработчик $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container') и по клику на ссылку "другой страницы", мы в блок с id="pjax-container" подгружаем тот материал который находится у нас на сайте по адресу site.ru/page/2.

Так понятнее?

Comment: Можете тут объяснить кратко...

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что такая технология будет работать, только в тех браузерах, который поддерживают history.pushState API. Список таковых можно посмотреть по это ссылке:
http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

Comment: А для остальных браузеров как реализовывать?

Comment: Боюсь, что никак.